# Stock LED overriding my LED setting

Tags: android, android-notifications

So I am writing an app that will use the LED to notify users of anything when the screen is OFF. Below is how I used it to work:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification();
notification.ledARGB = 0xFFFFFF00;
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
notification.ledOnMS = 100;
notification.ledOffMS = 100;
notificationManager.notify(Constants.LED_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

It works fine, but problem occurs when my device (Galaxy S5) has missed calls, and the stock LED notification for missed calls overrides my LED setting all the time. Is there a way to override the stock LED settings, and have it display mine instead? I've tried fiddling with

```
notification.priority
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: does the missed call occure before or after you show your notification, IIRC it is first come first serve for the LED light

Comment: I tested it few more times, and it does seem to be a first come first serve. I guess the only solution is to make sure I get there first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to override the stock LED settings, and have it display mine instead?

Not in general. Control over the LED is up to the device manufacturer, not you. Or, quoting the documentation, "Since hardware varies, you are not guaranteed that any of the values you pass are honored exactly."

Also, bear in mind that not all devices have LEDs that a `Notification` can control, sometimes because the device does not have an LED at all.